# iPhone, Order UIImages Programmatically

Tags: iphone

Essentially I would like to add a UIImage programmatically to my interface, using:

```
[[self view] addSubview: myImage]
```

However, I would like to add the image BEHIND an existing image already present in the interface builder.  Is there a method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[[self view] insertSubview:myImage atIndex:i]
```

i specifies the z index, where a higher index will be above a view with a lower index, so if i = 0 the view will be at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

UIView has a number of methods for inserting subviews into different places.

If you know which subview you want it to go behind you could use:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
```

Or if you know the index try:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

If you make the existing image an IBOutlet you could use the first method I mentioned.